# Getting horizontal scroll in mobile when close the menu

Tags: jquery, css, anime.js

I am using [anime.js](https://animejs.com/) and displaying the menu on mobile. I am getting a horizontal scroll on mobile.

I added `display:none` so that my menu will hide and when user click on the menu then I am adding the `display block` using the script but the issue is, after closing the menu I am still getting the scroll

Script adding the class

```
 $('html').addClass('noscroll');
```

and added below css

```
 html.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So that scroll will hide. Then also I am getting an issue if I close the menu.

Would you help me out with this issue?

I am using the below code.

```js
function menuOpen() {
  $('.menu-background').css('display', 'block');
  anime({
    targets: '.menu-background',
    translateX: ['100vw', 0],
    duration: 1300,
    easing: 'cubicBezier(0.44, -0.01, 0.08, 0.99)'
  });

}
$('.menu-trigger').on('click', function() {
  menuOpen();
});

function menuClose() {
  anime({
    targets: '.menu-background',
    translateX: [0, '100vw'],
    delay: 300,
    duration: 1300,
    easing: 'cubicBezier(0.44, -0.01, 0.08, 0.99)'
  });
}

// trigger menu animation on icon click
$('.menu-icon-close').on('click', function() {
  menuClose();
});
```

```css
.menu-trigger,
.menu-icon-close {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-trigger,
  .menu-icon-close {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #04dcff;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-background {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-trigger">Open</div>

<div class="menu-background">
  <div class="menu-icon-close">close</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking right direction - `overflow` would solve the problem. But in your code, I can't see where you're adding `overflow`.

One of the solutions would be to add a static overflow for X-axis to whole `body`:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Another solution, as you said, add it when necessary using JS.

```
function menuClose() {
  $('.menu-background').hide(300);
  anime({
    targets: '.menu-background',
    translateX: [0, '100vw'],
    delay: 300,
    duration: 1300,
    easing: 'cubicBezier(0.44, -0.01, 0.08, 0.99)'
  });
}
```

Comment: Apologize for the late reply Give me some time to check

Comment: I tried the first one. I am not getting the scroll but menu going left  right.

Answer (score 0):

You can set display none on function menuClose using delay 1300 and queue.

```
$('.menu-background').delay(1300).queue(function(next) {
      $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
      next();
  });
```

```js
function menuOpen() {
  $('.menu-background').css('display', 'block');
  anime({
    targets: '.menu-background',
    translateX: ['100vw', 0],
    duration: 1300,
    easing: 'cubicBezier(0.44, -0.01, 0.08, 0.99)'
  });

}
$('.menu-trigger').on('click', function() {
  menuOpen();
});

function menuClose() {
  anime({
    targets: '.menu-background',
    translateX: [0, '100vw'],
    delay: 300,
    duration: 1300,
    easing: 'cubicBezier(0.44, -0.01, 0.08, 0.99)'
  });
  $('.menu-background').delay(1300).queue(function(next) {
      $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
      next();
  });
}

// trigger menu animation on icon click
$('.menu-icon-close').on('click', function() {
  menuClose();
});
```

```css
.menu-trigger,
.menu-icon-close {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-trigger,
  .menu-icon-close {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #04dcff;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-background {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-trigger">Open</div>

<div class="menu-background">
  <div class="menu-icon-close">close</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am still getting the horizontal scroll

Comment: use menu-background parent overflow hidden, like body { overflow: hidden; } or if menu-background have any parent element.